# AEM XTM Translation Connector needs to be proxied

Tags: proxy, osgi, adobe, aem, crx

I am currently working in a AEM 6.5 environment trying to setup the **XTM Translation Connector**. I have successfully configured this on my *local* environment by doing the following:

1. Installing the **XTM Translation Connector** content package
2. Configuring credential (Web Service URI, XTM Client Name, User ID, Password) into */mnt/overlay/cq/translation/cloudservices/editor.html/conf/corp/settings/cloudconfigs/translation/xtm/xtm-translation*
3. When I click the *Verify* button I am prompted with the message:

> Connection parameters correct.

That said when I follow these same steps in my *dev*, *stage*, *prod* environments in a different network than my *local*, I am prompted with the message:

> Connection parameters incorrect.

I dove into the logs and found:

> [com.xtm.translation.connector.xtm-for-aem.core:1.5.2.SNAPSHOT]
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException invoking *Web_Service_URI*: connect timed out

I happen to know that this network uses a proxy server for external connections and reaching out to the internet. So I tried configuring the **Apache HTTP Components Proxy Configuration** in */system/console/configMgr* and then testing the *XTM Translation Connector* connection again but it doesn't even seems like the *XTM Translation Connector* is even trying to use the proxy when it tries connecting based on error.log messages.

How can I get this **XTM Translation Connector** to use this proxy ?

Any thoughts on this are welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Try Day Commons HTTP client 3.1 configuration

Comment: Can you access that URL from the server which host AEM itself? (Like using curl or wget). My guess is that a firewall rule is blocking the access.